# ORacle outer apply combination with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, outer-apply

why this two queries have two different result :

1. First query:

> ```
>         select c.customer_id, oo.order_id
>           from co.CUSTOMERS c
>          outer apply (select *
>                         from co.orders o
>                        where o.customer_id = c.CUSTOMER_ID
>                        order by o.order_id desc fetch first 1 rows only) oo
>          where c.CUSTOMER_ID = 22
>            and oo.order_id = 10000
> ```

2. Second query:

> ```
>         select c.customer_id, oo.order_id
>           from co.CUSTOMERS c
>          outer apply (select *
>                         from co.orders o
>                        where o.customer_id = c.CUSTOMER_ID
>                        order by o.order_id desc fetch first 1 rows only) oo
>          where c.CUSTOMER_ID = 22
>            and oo.order_id = 10000
>          group by c.customer_id, oo.order_id
> ```

the data of  co.CUSTOMERS c

```
select * from co.CUSTOMERS c   where c.customer_id=22
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | EMAIL_ADDRESS | FULL_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | raymond.bailey@internalmail | Raymond Bailey |

the data of co.orders

```
select * from co.orders o where o.customer_id=22
order by o.order_id  desc
```

| ORDER_ID | ORDER_DATETIME | CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_STATUS | STORE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1819 | 11-MAR-19 07.20.17.942291 AM | 22 | COMPLETE | 22 |
| 1435 | 07-JAN-19 03.57.14.316173 PM | 22 | COMPLETE | 1 |
| 511 | 19-JUL-18 06.24.36.024192 AM | 22 | COMPLETE | 1 |
| 184 | 26-APR-18 05.13.15.426435 AM | 22 | COMPLETE | 1 |

First query return nothing
**but** Second query return below :

| CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 22 | 10000 |

Comment: Can you post a reproducible test case?  Preferably as text that we can copy & paste or a link to a dbfiddle.uk/ liveSQL/ etc.  You've posted data for one of the two tables but not the other.

Comment: What's your oracle version? and patch level?

Comment: I test on oracle 12.c and 19 (livesql.oracle.com)

Comment: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ln4vwlkh85doz6nx0fmxcab72

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. I've raised this for you.

Comment: tnx chris, could you give me bug number or how can i find patch for this bug

Comment: It's 32788539; though it's unpublished. There's no fix at this stage, I don't have timescales for when this will be ready